# What Repository do I need to add to my Artifactory so I can get Typesafe's SBT plugins?

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe

I'm trying to build a play-framework application behind a heavily firewalled corporate network. I use an Artifactory to supply all of the project dependencies - there's no other way of connecting to the outside world. I've actually just git-cloned the starter project from the Play documentation.

When I sbt build the first error I see is a failure to download a plugin from the private repo:

```
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.5.10
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\salimfadhley\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.play\sbt-plugin\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\2.5.10\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== my-maven-proxy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://private_code_repo.bigco.com:8081/artifactory/virtual-sbt/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.5.10/sbt-plugin-2.5.10.pom
[warn] ==== my-ivy-proxy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://private_code_repo.bigco.com:8081/artifactory/virtual-sbt/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.10/ivys/ivy.xml
```

It looks like there's a missing repository in my Artifactory configuration. That's easily rectified if only I knew which repository I needed to add.

Since this is a Typesafe.org project the logical place to look was in one of TypeSafe's repositories: It looks like it wants to get a the sbt-plugin version 2.5.10, however I can see the highest numbered version of the plugin that has been published is actually 2.4.x

https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.4.0-T2/

In other words, how on earth would this get resolved, even if I could connect to the Internet? The thing that it's trying to find does not actually exist! How can I rectify this to make the project actually buildable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin is available from the following Ivy repository: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/

More generally, the page about [proxy repositories](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html) in the SBT docs has some usefull information (including the above URL), although I don't think all of it is very clear.

Comment: Excellent, the problem was that I had forgotten to include the plugins repo. Once I added this everything went perfectly.